# Shared calendar app compatible with Google Calendar that supports recurring events?

Tags: ios, calendar

I used [CalenMob](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/calenmob-google-calendar-client/id514917848?mt=8) for a year.

I really like its **GoogleCalendar compatibility**, that allow me to work on shared calendars.
Unfortunately this app doesn't provide **recurrent events support**. To get it I have to buy the CalenMobPro app. I decided to invest on it, but customer reviews say that there is a problematic sync bug since the last update in November, and it hasn't yet been fixed.

So I'm looking for an alternative. Free or not, it doesn't matter but I insist on the **intuitive interface** and **the GUI efficiency** of the app. It would be nice for the app to be universal (running on both iPhone and iPad), but it's not strictly required.

Comment: Google Calendar can be supported by anything that supports ICal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using an Apple product (which I presume you are from the tags), then you can just sync your Google account in the System Preferences and select Mail/Contacts/Calendar (User accounts tab on Mac). This will give you the option of choosing which apps you want to sync (eg. calendar).

Comment: Agreed, the native iOS calendar app meets all the needs specified. (Shared Google calendar compatibility, recurrent events, intuitive interface)

Comment: Can I add my GoogleCalendar on iOS Cal without adding my email account on iOS Mail?

Comment: @Fractaliste I you can edit what apps use your email in the settings under Internet Accounts (or similar).